# Python, How to bind the change in a module variable to my script?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6

I have a module, that according to mouse clicks changes a variable's value.
Now I want to import that module in a script, and then print wherever the module's variable value changes.

Comment: show your code. `tkinter` has classes `StringVar`, `IntVar()`, (etc.) to keep value, and you can assign function to this values and class will execute this function when value is changed. Look for [StringVar.trace()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) BTW: you can also build similar class from scratch.

Comment: The code is too long, the procedure I need is how to call a function in my script, from the module

Comment: `import module ; module.function()`

Comment: I want it the other way around, the module to force call a function in the script

Comment: your function in module should get function as agument (so called `callback`) (like `command=` in `Button` or `bind()` or `after()` get function name) - `function_from_modules( function_from_script )` and then it can execute it using `()` - `function_from_script()`.

Comment: You can't do what you want, unless this variable is one of the Tkinter variable classes (`StringVar`, etc).

Comment: Thanks guys !!! Solved the issue by passing a callback in the constructor, then used that callback in my StringVar !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem by passing a callback into the my class constructor.
Then used that callback in a StringVar.

In script.py

```
import module
def script_callback(a, b, c):
    print(module.canvas.var.get())
canvas = module.MyClass(callback=script_callback)
```

In module.py:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(callback):
        self.var = StringVar()
        self.var.trace('w', callback)  
        self.var.set(data)
```

Thanks to Bryan and furas.